# Open url from terminal in chrome

Tags: command-line, firefox, chrome

[image]

When I click on the link just echoed, it is opened in firefox.

Earlier such links from terminal were opened in chrome.

But then I made firefox as my default browser. Then on wards these links are opened in firefox.

But now I want to open links in chrome. I had made chrome as default browser.

Still these links are opened in firefox. How to solve this?

I am using  **elementary 14.04**.

I tried to recreate this in ubuntu. 
But there it is working fine.
When I changed to chrome as default browser, links from terminal are opened in chrome.

**What I have tried**

I uninstalled firefox.
Now the links are opening in chrome.

Then I again installed firefox.
Now the links are agian opening in firefox

My Desktop Environment is `pantheon`

Terminal emulator is `pantheon terminal`

Comment: What terminal emulator are you using? What desktop environment are you using?

Comment: @Patrick pantheon is the DE. pantheon terminal is the terminal emulator

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if there's xdg-settings in elementary OS but try this:

```
xdg-settings set default-web-browser google-chrome.desktop
```

Comment: Sorry. this is not working

Answer (score 2):

I got the solution.

Even though I made chrome as my default browser through settings in chrome, it was not changed in the system settings.

So I should change

```
System Settings > Applications > Web Browser to chrome.
```